# How To Create An App That Allows For Profile Picture Upload/Change?

Tags: android, image, android-activity, parse-platform, android-camera

I have been searching high and low to find an example of how to implement profile picture changes within my app. I want to allow persons to add/change their profile image using Parse.com (Similar to all social media apps today).

**For example:** Twitter, Facebook, Instagram and so on, they all allow you to take/upload a profile image and that image is saved and can be viewed later on.

I have had no luck finding any material that covers how to do such a thing and no else seems to be understanding what I'm trying to achieve here:

[An Image Downloaded From Parse Stay On Screen Even After You Exit And Reopen App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561551/an-image-downloaded-from-parse-stay-on-screen-even-after-you-exit-and-reopen-app)

So far in my app the user can take a picture with the camera intent or upload an image from gallery and that image is displayed in an Image View perfectly.

**The problem is:** when I exit and re-open the app the image inside of the Image View is no longer displayed (it is gone).

How can I solve this problem?

**MainActivity:**

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static final int TAKE_PIC_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
        public static final int CHOOSE_PIC_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 2;

        private Uri mMediaUri;

        private TextView mChangeProfilePic;
        protected ImageView mPreviewImageView;
        private Button mSaveChangesBtn;
        public ImageView mProfilePic;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });


            //Initialize variables
            mChangeProfilePic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changeProfileImageTxt);
            mPreviewImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
            mSaveChangesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveProfileChangesBtn);
            mSaveChangesBtn.setEnabled(false);

            final Button mNextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextBtn);
            mNextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentNext = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentNext);
                }
            });


            //Change profile image
            //set onlClick to TextView
            mChangeProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Change Pic Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //show dialog
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Upload or Take a photo");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Upload", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //upload image
                            Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            choosePictureIntent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, CHOOSE_PIC_REQUEST_CODE);

                            mSaveChangesBtn.setEnabled(true);

                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Take Photo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //take photo
                            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            mMediaUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                            if (mMediaUri == null) {
                                //display error
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry there was an error! Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                mSaveChangesBtn.setEnabled(false);

                            } else {
                                takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
                                startActivityForResult(takePicture, TAKE_PIC_REQUEST_CODE);

                                mSaveChangesBtn.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });//End change profile image onClick Listener


            //Save profile changes button
            //Also uploads content to parse and pulls it back same time
            mSaveChangesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //create parse object for image to upload
                    final ParseObject imageUpload = new ParseObject("ImageUploads");
                    try {
                        //convert image to bytes for upload.
                        byte[] fileBytes = FileHelper.getByteArrayFromFile(MainActivity.this, mMediaUri);
                        if (fileBytes == null) {
                            //there was an error
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There was an error. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            mSaveChangesBtn.setEnabled(false);
                        } else {

                            fileBytes = FileHelper.reduceImageForUpload(fileBytes);
                            String fileName = FileHelper.getFileName(MainActivity.this, mMediaUri, "image");
                            final ParseFile file = new ParseFile(fileName, fileBytes);
                            imageUpload.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {

                                        imageUpload.put("imageContent", file);
                                        imageUpload.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                                                         @Override
                                                                         public void done(ParseException e) {
                                                                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success Uploading iMage!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                                             //Retrieve the recently saved image from Parse
                                                                             queryParseProfileImages(imageUpload);

                                                                             mSaveChangesBtn.setEnabled(false);
                                                                         }
                                                                     }

                                        );
                                    } else {
                                        //there was an error
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        mSaveChangesBtn.setEnabled(false);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e1.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }//End onClick(View v)

            });//End onClick Listener


//This method queries for the most recent picture taken
ParseQuery<ParseObject> imagesQuery = new ParseQuery<>("ImageUploads");
            imagesQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt");
            imagesQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> images, ParseException e) {
                    if(e == null){

                        //for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {

                            final String imgUrl = images.get(0).getParseFile("imageContent").getUrl();


                            mProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
                            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(imgUrl).into(mProfilePic);

                        //}
                        //images.pinInBackground();

                        //profileImageId = profImgObj.getObjectId();
                        //Log.d(TAG, "The object id is: " + profileImageId);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });



        }//End onCreate


        //Method containing ParseQuery to download/pull back the image that was uploaded to Parse
        //Inside the Image View
        private void queryParseProfileImages(final ParseObject imageUploadPassed) {

            ParseFile userImageRetrievedObj = (ParseFile) imageUploadPassed.get("imageContent");
            userImageRetrievedObj.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {


                        final String imgUrl = imageUploadPassed.getParseFile("imageContent").getUrl();


                        mProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
                        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(imgUrl).into(mProfilePic);

                        imageUploadPassed.pinInBackground();


                    } else {
                        // something went wrong
                    }
                }
            });


        }


        //inner helper method
        private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int mediaTypeImage) {

            if (isExternalStorageAvailable()) {
                //get the URI
                //get external storage dir
                File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "UPLOADIMAGES");
                //create subdirectore if it does not exist
                if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                    //create dir
                    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {

                        return null;
                    }
                }
                //create a file name
                //create file
                File mediaFile = null;
                Date now = new Date();
                String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(now);

                String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator;
                if (mediaTypeImage == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
                    mediaFile = new File(path + "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg");
                }
                //return file uri
                Log.d("UPLOADIMAGE", "FILE: " + Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));

                return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
            } else {

                return null;
            }

        }

        //check if external storage is mounted. helper method
        private boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == CHOOSE_PIC_REQUEST_CODE) {
                    if (data == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image cannot be null!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        mMediaUri = data.getData();
                        //set previews
                        mPreviewImageView.setImageURI(mMediaUri);

                        //Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                        //Log.e("URI", mMediaUri.toString());

                        //Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");


                    }
                } else {

                    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    mediaScanIntent.setData(mMediaUri);
                    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                    //set previews

                    mPreviewImageView.setImageURI(mMediaUri);

                }

            } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great question, well formatted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I have to say that this a really well formulated question and I would be happy that every guy with few reputation asks so good formulated questions.

The problem you encounter is basically an issue with the Android Activity lifecycle. I guess, the problem is really trivial: I see nowhere in your Activity `onCreate()` a place where you retrieve the image from Parse: your download method is only called in a `onClickListener`.

So instead of having it here, I would extract it to a `private` method, kind of something like this:

**Edit:**

```
   private void queryImagesFromParse(){
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> imagesQuery = new ParseQuery<>("User");
        imagesQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> imagesItems, ParseException e) {
                if(e == null){

                    ParseUser userCurrentOfParse = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                    if(userCurrentOfParse != null) {
                        //final String imgUrl = imageUploadPassed.getParseFile("imageContent").getUrl();
                        final String imgUrl = userCurrentOfParse.getParseFile("userProfilePics").getUrl();


                        mHomeProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userHomeProfilePicImageView);
                        Picasso.with(HomeActivity.this).load(imgUrl).into(mHomeProfilePic);

                        //imageUploadPassed.pinInBackground();

                       // profileImageId = imageUploadPassed.getObjectId();
                        //Log.d(TAG, "The object id is: " + profileImageId);
                    }

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

(The code above is just to give an rough idea, I would be surprised if it compiles).

And then, you call this method at the end of the `onCreate()` (`onStart` could work as well, but I'd prefer `onCreate()`). Of course, you can call this method also from the place where it was before (that is actually what happens if you literally `extract` the method `Right-Click` > `Refractor` > `Extract Method`)

Btw, very good that you use `Picasso` but it could be better to initialise it with the `Context` of your `Activity` so `Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(imgUrl).into(mProfilePic);` instead of `Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imgUrl).into(mProfilePic);` (should be 1 ns faster!)

**Edit:** Also be sure that the image is being upload and queried from the User table on Parse this will ensure that each user will see their own image(currently logged in user's image) and not that of every other user that uploads the next image.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and for your compliment I thought I was gonna be left stranded with this question with no help whatsoever so your help is greatly appreciated. When I get home I will try your approach and if I run into any further problems I will let you know.

Comment: I have made changes to the code and it still doesn't work I might not have done what you said correctly but i'm not sure. What I did was to create a method outside of the onCreate and put the contents of the query inside that method than call that method inside the onClick within onCreate.

Comment: Yes, perfect but you forgot to call it as well in the `onCreate`, don't you? You need to call it as well in the `onCreate` to make it load the first time.

Comment: Oh okay, I will tweak it later when I get home and keep you up to date on what happens next.

Comment: I made changes again (Still have a problem though). Check my edited code and look where you see the comment that says "//This method queries for the most recent picture taken", that query was able to allow the image to be displayed in the Image View even when I exit and re-open the app. So that's good BUT the new problem which I already knew would happen, is that if I sign into the app as a second user and take a pic with that user then log out of the first user and log back in, the first user's pic now changes to the same pic as the second user

Comment: One of the ideas that I came up with and have tried to fix this new issue, was to use "getObjectId()" to retrieve the object id of the image just as I am saving it to Parse and then pass that object id to a query outside of the onClick so that way every time a new pic is taken, regardless of the user, each user will not have the same profile pic being displayed but the problem I faced with this was that the query inside of the onClick wasn't able to pass the objectId when the app reopens and it gave me a null pointer error because of the onCreate being restored without the objectId being saved

Comment: Wait, I do not get it, are you not supposed to recreate this view every time, you log in? I guess I have a problem in knowing which workflow you want :)

Comment: Well the workflow should be like this, when I log in the image that was previously saved to parse and in the image view should still be showing as a profile pic until the user changes it if they want. But the problem I am having now is that based on how the newly added query is designed if one user uploaded a picture to parse the query will fetch the newly uploaded but and all users will see the change, but I want only the user who changes their pic to be the only ones who can see the change, not everybody

Comment: And I tried to use the ifCurrentUser() method but this didn't work. So I am assuming the only way to make this work is to get the object ID of the picture at the same time I am about to save the page to parse and then query back for that same object id, then maybe this way each user will only see their uploaded pic. But the problem with this is that I can't fetch the object ID when the app is restarted because its null in the beginning

Comment: If I can save the object ID of the image as it is uploaded to Parse for later use then I can display the proper image for the respective user who uploaded it.

Comment: hahaha, I just got it. Sorry, yes you definitely missed something. Extend the user class in you Parse database to have a file contained with each user (add a column of type ParseFile in the data explorer). Then call `getCurrentUser.getParseFile(file)` assuming `getCurrentUser` is not null because you logged in and it'll work

Comment: Everything is working perfectly now. Thank you very much and if I post any more questions on this site I do hope more people like you help because not many people on here actually put out the effort to help, they criticize more than help and most just abandon the person but thanks a lot for the continued help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Also I edited your answer to add the changes so that other persons will benefit. Constructive **knowledge should always be shared** so that everyone can learn and be better. Thanks again

Comment: You show a very good programmer spirit, please go on and spread it! A great programmer is just a programmer with great habits and outstanding spirit!

Comment: Thanks! I try. Keep on helping others it's a good thing you're doing.